# Given the same features, do logistic regression and neural networks produce the same output?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, logistic-regression

I have a binary classification problem. I have variables (features) var1, var2, var3, ..., var14.

Using these variables (aka features) in a logistic regression, I get their weights.

If I use the same set of variables in a neural network:

- Should I get a different output?

  or
- Should I get the same output?

I developed a ROC Curve, and I have both lines overlaying on each other. I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question if you don't provide both the plots of the ROC Curve, more details about your neural network (such as the output layer, which active function you are using, which problem you're trying to solve, size of dataset, etc.)